# Second Derivative in MMA

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to ask, why the following second derivative is wrong in MMA

```
xx = {{x1, x2, x12}}
ccc = {{c11, c12, c13}, {c21, c22, c23}, {c31, c32, c33}}
fff = 0.5 xx.ccc. Transpose[xx]
FF1 = D[fff, {xx, 2}]
```

**FF1** must be equal to **ccc**, but ...

Another question is:

**Can we convert this code to C/Fortran in MMA without ACEGEN now?**

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Well, the second derivative will be symmetric, but `ccc` is not symmetric.  Also, the way arrays work in *M*, you probably want to change `xxx` and `fff` as follows: `xx = {x1, x2, x12}; fff = 0.5 ccc.xx.xx; FF1 = D[fff, {xx, 2}]``

Comment: @Michael E2 okay thanks !

Comment: "can we convert this loop to C/Fortran in MMA without ACEGEN now?" Which loop? There is none.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I have changed.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code supplied in the question with small corrections and with the use of `MatrixForm` to better see the results:

```
xx = {x1, x2, x12};
ccc = {{c11, c12, c13}, {c21, c22, c23}, {c31, c32, c33}};
fff = 0.5 xx.ccc.xx ;
FF1 = D[fff, {xx, 2}] // MatrixForm
```

This produces

[image]

```
0.5 (ccc + Transpose[ccc]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

We see that *Mathematica* computes $FF1 = \frac{1}{2} (ccc+ccc^T)$, which is actually correct.

$\displaystyle f=\frac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^T C \mathbf{x}$

$\displaystyle \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{1}{2} (C + C^T) \mathbf{x}$

$\fbox{${ \displaystyle \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} = \frac{1}{2} (C + C^T)} $}$

See, for example, *Appendix A.3 Vector and Matrix Differentiation* in Horn, **Robot Vision**, MIT Press, pp. 459, 461.

Also,

$C = \frac{1}{2} (C+C^T) + \frac{1}{2} (C-C^T)$, known as the symmetric and antisymmetric parts of $C$.

$C=\frac{1}{2} (C+C^T) \iff C$ is symmetric.

Comment: It could be improved by showing the Mathematica code that computes the formula you have posted. And also providing an explanation for *why* MMA apparently gives a "wrong" result.

Comment: Yes, excellent!  Will do.

Comment: @mjw, Transpose[xx].ccc.xx , is correct???

Comment: The Mathematica Documentation "Multiplying Vectors and Matrices Tutorial" states:  It is important to realize that you can use "dot" for both left- and right-multiplication of vectors by matrices. The Wolfram Language makes no distinction between "row" and "column" vectors. Dot carries out whatever operation is possible. (In formal terms, a.b contracts the last index of the tensor a with the first index of b.)

Comment: If your question is about multiplying a vector by a matrix, in this example if $\mathbf{x}$ is a column vector, then $\mathbf{x}^T C \mathbf{x}$ is correct.  If $\mathbf{x}$ is a row vector, then we would write it as $\mathbf{x} C \mathbf{x}^T.$  Mathematica makes *no distinction* and carries out the one that is permitted.